# run time 1004 Error on .Refresh BackgroundQuery

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

After some updating I have been able to come up with a close to working code. One of the only problems that I am encountering is that the macro is not scraping the data from the last page. For yesterday's data there were 6 pages of data, but the macro is only scraping through page 5. But the weird thing is if i were to scrape data with the same code from 2 days ago, I am able to retrieve the data on all either 7 or 8 pages. I am unsure of why this is happening. Any ideas? Here is the updated code.

```
'Macro to query Delinquency Status Search for DFB Counties
'Run Monday to pull data from Friday

Sub queryActivityDailyMforFWorking()

Dim nextrow As Integer, i As Long
Dim dates
dates = Date - 1

i = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

Do

'i = i + 1
Application.StatusBar = "Processing Page " & i
nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlToLeft).Column + 1

    'With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    '"URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i + county + x & "&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1", _
    'Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))

    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & "&county_1=11,%2012,%2013,%2014,%2015,%2016,%2017,%2018,%2019,%2020,%2021,%2022,%2023,%2024,%2025,%2026,%2027,%2028,%2080,%2029,%2030,%2031,%2032,%2033,%2034,%2035,%2036,%2037,%2038,%2039,%2040,%2041,%2042,%2043,%2044,%2045,%2046,%2047,%2048,%2049,%2050,%2051,%2052,%2053,%2054,%2055,%2056,%2057,%2058,%2059,%2079,%2060,%2061,%2062,%2063,%2064,%2067,%2068,%2069,%2065,%2066,%2070,%2071,%2072,%2073,%2078,%2074,%2075,%2076,%2077&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1", _
    Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))





    '.Name = _
    "2015&search_1.x=40&search_1.y=11&date=on&county_1=AL&lic_num_del=&lic_num_rep=&status=NS&biz_name=&owner_name="
    .FieldNames = False
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "10"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False




'autofit columns
Columns("A:G").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

'check for filter, if not then turn on filter
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter
End If
i = i + 1
End With

ActiveCell.value = ActiveCell.Value * 2
ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Select

Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value)

Application.StatusBar = False

'Align text left
Cells.Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
.WrapText = False
.Orientation = 0
.AddIndent = False
.IndentLevel = 0
.ShrinkToFit = False
.ReadingOrder = xlContext
.MergeCells = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Even if there were true, it would keep iterating on through. I have this same code written for a different search, and even if it had less than 25 page, it would still keep iterating on through until it got to 25.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but that doesn't seem to make sense in what i am doing. in the sense that the other Sub i am running, same code mind you, just different search code, runs with no problems and I know that 13 does not exist, but it still runs through and iterates.

Comment: I tried a different date and the code is able to iterate through and not come up with an error

Comment: The query won't actually execute until it hits .Refresh BackgroundQuery so it could actually be anything in the query before that. Maybe try commenting it out one at a time until you don't get the error anymore.

Comment: With the code the way it is right now, if you were to execute the code, it will throw the error. But when I change the date to scrape information from 12/16, it scrapes through with no problems. I just don't understand why I can scrape data from other days, but not yesterday. I already tried to comment out lines before .refresh backgroundquery and i still receive the same error.

Answer (score 1):

My solution (maybe add formatting to bring it back to column A):

```
Sub QueryDelinquencyTest()
Dim nextrow As Integer, i As Integer
Dim dates
dates = Date - 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Do While i < 25 'this is the page range to be captured.
Application.StatusBar = "Processing Page " & i
nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & "&county_1=AL&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1", _
    Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "10"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
End With

i = i + 1
Loop
Cells.Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought that the formatting was there already for it to start in column A? Maybe i am missing that part and don't see where it is. i see the changes that you made and can't seem to figure out what you took out to get the columns to start in column A. Also, when i try and add an autofilter, i receive an error saying that the autofilter method of range class failed. Any ideas on that?

Comment: How would you also keep track of when you get to the end of the search results? I want to tell the code to stop search when it does not have anymore data to pull. Do you think i would have to modify this code to incorporate the html tags as well?

Comment: There was formatting for columns A through G but the only thing in those columns was some not found info way down at the bottom; everything else was pushed way over to the right. You 'll have to run it, see what it does, and then decide what to do for formatting. As for stopping it when you reach the end, just do something like if the right arrow button not found then format and exit

Comment: Yea, i ran the macro and saw that the actual information was pushed on over to the right. I will play around with it some more. How would I start the coding for if the arrow doesn't exit? Would it be finding the html element of that right arrow button?

Comment: When it gets to a blank page it puts "No Activity Information found." in Column A. I would change your Do while to say something like while the value in cell a not equal to "No Activity Information found."

Comment: Ok. I must be missing something. When I type this code, it gives me a Out of Memory Error. Do While ActiveSheet.Cells.Value <> "No Activity Information Found" 'my code from here. Am i missing a piece of information that i am not implementing or missing?

Comment: I'd try specifically searching the cell for the value and not the entire worksheet. At least narrow it down to Column A.

Comment: And maybe use Do Until instead

Comment: When I try this, i get an error of type mismatch. I am not allowed to do this? Do.....Loop Until Range("A1:A60").Value <> Cells.Value("No Activity Information Found")

Comment: Also, how would i get my variable i to increment as well?

Comment: I got part of it working with that. No my problem is as soon as it find that there are no activity information found, it stops right there and doesn't continue through all of the pages. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I have so far when declaring a variable for each county.

```
'Macro to query Delinquency Status Search for DFB Counties
'Run Monday to pull data from Friday

Sub queryActivityDailyMforF()

Dim nextrow As Integer, i As Long
Dim dates
dates = Date - 1
Dim x, county1, county2, county3, county4, county5, county6, county7, county8, county9, county10, county11, county12
county1 = "county_1=16"
county2 = "county_1=21"
county3 = "county_1=23"
county4 = "county_1=32"
county5 = "county_1=36"
county6 = "county_1=41"
county7 = "county_1=46"
county8 = "county_1=53"
county9 = "county_1=54"
county10 = "county_1=57"
county11 = "county_1=60"
county12 = "county_1=66"

'Dim myString
'myString = "No Activity Information Found"
'Dim lastRow As Long
'Dim county
'Dim site As String

'Dim rng As Range
'Dim firstCell As String

'lastRow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

'If Not rng Is Nothing Then firstCell = rng.Address

'Do Until myString <> lastRow And InStr("&county_1=66", "St. Lucie")
Do

'Do While i < 4
'For i = 1 To lastRow
'Set rng = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A:A").find(What:=Cells(i, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
'Do While lastRow <> myString
    Application.StatusBar = "Processing Page " & i
    nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
     '   "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & "&county_1=16&county_1=21&county_1=23&county_1=32&county_1=36&county_1=41&county_1=46&county_1=53&county_1=54&county_1=57&county_1=60&county_1=66&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1", _
      '  Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))

        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & county & x & "&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1", _
        Destination:=Range("A" & nextrow))



        '.Name = _
        "2015&search_1.x=40&search_1.y=11&date=on&county_1=AL&lic_num_del=&lic_num_rep=&status=NS&biz_name=&owner_name="
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "10"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

    'autofit columns
    Columns("A:G").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

   'check for filter, if not then turn on filter
   ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A:G").AutoFilter
    End If

    'If Not rng Is Nothing Then
     '   If rng.Address = firstCell Then Exit Do
      '  End If


 'site = "https://www.myfloridalicense.com/delinquency_results.asp?SID=&page=" & i & "&county_1=16&county_1=21&county_1=23&county_1=32&county_1=36&county_1=41&county_1=46&county_1=53&county_1=54&county_1=57&county_1=60&county_1=66&status=NS&send_date=" & dates & "&search_1.x=1"
 'county = "&coutny_1=66"



End With
'Next
i = i + 1
Loop Until x = 12

x = x + 1
'Loop Until InStr(site, county) And ActiveCell.Value = myString
'Wend
Application.StatusBar = False

'Align text left
Cells.Select
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
    .WrapText = False
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlContext
    .MergeCells = False
End With

'Next
'Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: you have to set x = 1 before the loop. Also i isn't set to anything so "Processing Page" & i won't be valid.

Comment: Let me give you some advice I learned the hard way, only work on one piece at a time and get it to work before moving on to the next. For example, you changed your looping structure and created all those variables, so if it fails, you won't know which part doesn't work.

Comment: Yea, i know. I am all over the place. I just want to get this done. Haha. I will keep working at it and see what i can come up with. Thank you